# c# extension method to define method that behaves like a static class / type method, not an instance method

Tags: c#, timezone, extension-methods, static-methods

I have this static method in a class:

```
public class MyTimeZoneHelperClass {

        public static TimeZoneInfo EST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

        public static DateTime Convert_UTC_to_EST(this DateTime utcDateTime)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, EST);
        }

        public static DateTime NowEST()
        {
            return DateTime.UtcNow.Convert_UTC_to_EST();
        }
}
```

I just went to write an extension method like for the DateTime TYPE that I was going to name "EstNow" so I could use DateTime.EstNow like this code uses DateTime.UtcNow. If I had that, I wouldn't have to reference this static class above - MyTimeZoneHelperClass.NowEst - my code would be just a little cleaner, I wouldn't have to remember that class name / I would prefer one class here instead of two.

So extension methods don't work like that. They are static methods but then you need an instance of he class to call the method - duh!

Is this possible? Can I (preferably easily) get the compiler to recognize a new / custom static method on a type?

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly encourage you to call your field (ideally after making it a property) `EasternTime` instead of `EST`. Despite the time zone ID, it *isn't* EST - it's Eastern Time which varies between EST and EDT. (That's probably what you want anyway, but I'd strongly encourage you to avoid using "EST" as a synonym for "Eastern Time" when they're not the same thing.) I'd also encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions (no underscores, and use `Utc` instead of `UTC` etc).

Comment: According to my experience, I will never again use a DateTime directly anymore in my next projects.
I regularly read people advising this and I started to understand the benefit of it.
I would make an interface and an own implementation that encapsulates the DateTime with all functionality needed.
You could make it castable to DateTime for your legacy code.
This would solve your problem somehow, no? But especially for unit tests this appears to be extremely useful (e.g. by simulating a fake current time).

Comment: Word up dude. I gotta rock all those rules for work, I should develop the habit. So word up... but this is personal and maybe throwaway, I'm just trying to write this thing as fast as possible. :)

Comment: Word up Reno, I do need current date times for unit tests. Thanks. Mostly just curious. But yeah, for my immediate needs, DateTime.EstNow would be convenient.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't write "static extension" members to extend the type instead of instances of the type. It's just not part of C#. It has been *discussed*, and it *may* happen in the future, although I don't believe it's in the expected feature list for C# 9.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on the c# github as we speak: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2505

Open means it's not implemented yet. To summarise from it:

1. There is no workaround to this, nothing to try that would mitigate the missing functionality
2. There seems to be no interest to implement this at this point

> There is no one on the ldm who thinks this is worth championing right now.